# PYTHON A progress bar or self-updated timer when reading a large pdf file with PyPDF2 convert_from_path

Tags: python, timer, progress-bar, readfile, pypdf

I am trying to show a self-updated timer/progress bar when the system is reading the following file:

```
#initialize widgets
widgets = ['Reading data, please wait: ', pb.Percentage(), ' ', 
pb.Bar(marker=pb.RotatingMarker()), ' ', pb.ETA()]

#initialize timer
timer = pb.ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=1000000).start()

for i in range(0,1000000):
    timer.update(i)
    pages = convert_from_path(filepath + "\\" + file, poppler_path = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\PUG\poppler-0.67.0_x86\poppler-0.67.0\bin')
    timer.finish()
```

However, if I put the above code in for loop, the time will not update itself but until the file is finished reading.

Is there any way to print the progress and update the time, at the same time, the system is reading that large pdf file.

e.g. Reading file, please wait... Time escape: 1s<-- the time will update itself every second

after the system finished reading, the timer will no longer update.

Thx